# Explicacion del Cast para que sirve, y cuando usarlo?

Tags: java, cast

Hola tengo esta parte del codigo en un metodo

```
public lugar getlugar(int x){

    lugar l2=(lugar)lugares.get(x);
    return l2;
}
```

Quiero que me hagan el favor de explicarme  lo del cast porque no logro entenderlo.

Este es mi Main

```
public class Fabrica {

private String Descripcion;
private int capacidad;



ArrayList<lugar> lugares= new ArrayList<lugar>();


public static void main(String[] args){

Fabrica f=new Fabrica();

for (int x=0;x<10;x++) { 
    f.crearLugar();
}

f.numerolugares();
}

public void crearLugar(){
lugar l1=new lugar();
lugares.add(l1);
}

public void numerolugares(){
System.out.println("numero de lugares" +" "+ lugares.size());
}

public lugar getlugar(int x){

lugar l2=(lugar)lugares.get(x);
return l2;
}

public void agregarplaza(int p){

lugar l3=(lugar)getlugar(p);
l3.crearplazas();

}

public void getplaza(int p,int t){

lugar lugar1=(lugar)getlugar(p);
lugar1.crearplazas();

plazas plas=(plazas)lugar1.getplazas(t);

plas.Soy();

}
```

Lugar es una clase que tengo dentro del programa y Lugares es el nombre que tiene mi ArrayList.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. ¿Podrías por favor explicar lo que es `lugar` y `lugares`? No lograremos entender lo que eso representa en tu aplicación si no lo explicas. Gracias.

Comment: Leiste algo sobre casting en Java? tenes alguna duda en particular?

Comment: de paso, mira [ask] <- ACA.. tu pregunta es bastante pobre, ya que no decis que sabes hasta ahora, o despues de que leiste la documentacion que duda te quedo. Porque tal vez, te explicamos justamente lo que no entendes...

Comment: Yo entiendo el Casting para convertir el tipo de dato, pero en esta parte del codigo no logro entenderlo porque lo veo diferente.

Comment: No se muy bien que no entiendes. `ArrayList.get` podría (aunque en este caso no sería asi) devolver un objeto de tipo `object`. Como necesitas que sea de tipo `lugar`, haces un cast a ese tipo.Pero en este código no parece tener sentido, al ser `lugares` un arraylist tipado con lo que el objeto que devuelve siempre sera de tipo `lugar`

Comment: a que te referis con lo ves diferente.. si lo sacas, el compilador no infiere el tipo?

Answer (score 1):

Un casting es una operación especial que nos permite realizar una conversión entre diferentes tipos de variables.
Ejemplo:

```
 public class CastingApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int a = 0;

        double b=3.4;

        a=(int)b;

        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

Un casting se indica entre paréntesis con el tipo de dato al que queremos pasar, en este caso int. La variable a, contendrá un  3 y no un 3.4.

Answer (score 0):

El Cast es una operacion que permite que el objeto sea convertido en otro. Si comparte una estructura similar entre si, esto es recordando que son objetos y poseen la propiedad de Poliformismo. El "Casting" es Polimorfismo  implícito. En java todos los objetos derivan de la Clase Object.

Comment: PavelAcu, bienvenido a SOes. Me parece que tu explicacion es buena, pero muy general. Si pudieras [edit] tu respuesta para adaptarla a la situacion de la pregunta seria mucho mejor.